# How to add validation in ngx-intl-tel-input in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to validate ngx-intl-tel-input for mobile input field whenever user put wrong number or leave it blank.

I'm doing this:

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input
    [cssClass]="'form-control country-tel-code'"                             
    [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" 
    [enablePlaceholder]="true" 
    [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
    [searchCountryFlag]="true"
    [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
    [selectFirstCountry]="false" 
    [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Nigeria"
    [maxLength]="15" 
    [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name" 
    [phoneValidation]="true"
    [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode"
    formControlName="mobile" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && mobileRequired || mobileValid }">
</ngx-intl-tel-input>
<div *ngIf="submitted && f.mobile.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="mobileRequired">Mobile No. is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="mobileValid">Invalid Mobile No.</div>
</div>
```

& in my controller.ts file:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        if (this.registerForm.controls.mobile.errors.required) {
            this.mobileRequired = true;
        }
        if (!this.registerForm.controls.mobile.errors.validatePhoneNumber.valid) {
            this.mobileValid = true;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

But no message is given.
Please help!!!

Comment: do you have stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

I made a stackblitz demo to reproduce your issue. And everything works fine for me. Hope it will help you.

STACKBLITZ DEMO => https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-hrjsa3

Comment: Okay that helped me alot thanks. I have a one more question.

Comment: can I add a class on ngx-intl-tel-input tag [cssClass] property on a particular condition like: Currently I have this, [cssClass]="'form-control country-tel-code'"

Comment: But I want it to be like this, [cssClass]="'form-control country-tel-code { is-invalid: submitted && f.mobile.errors }'" i.e., is-invalid applied when both the values are true.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
[cssClass]="{ 'form-control' : 1, 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mobile.errors }"
```

This will work with Bootstrap